# What's the best way to lock a directory from remove & edits?

Tags: lock

I have a few directories that I want to lock. This lock should provide the following:

1. Disallow anyone (including myself) from removing from that directory without a password
2. Disallow anyone (including myself) from changing existing files in that directory and recursive directories without a password
3. It shouldn't prevent new files from being added by myself but should prevent it from others (but not root)

I am using `Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)`.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: with "chattr" you can protect files but I don't think you can set a password with it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent users from renaming files while providing write permissions on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93399/how-to-prevent-users-from-renaming-files-while-providing-write-permissions-on-li)

Comment: No need `chattr`, just a directory as root with 755 rights (default with common umask) on that dir

Comment: @Gilles Quénot would "acl" also be an option except as you mentioned with setting of directory as root?

Comment: No need complicated stuff. Just a simple root dir. Also check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types

Comment: @Gilles that doesn’t allow point 3, does it?

Comment: True, misreaded that point @StephenKitt